# Sum of diagonal elements in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a confusion matrix in BigQuery and I want to find the sum of diagonal elements in it. How can I do this using SQL

Here is the data

```
select 0 as predictedGroup , 60 as label0 , 20 as label1, 20 as label2
union all
select 1, 20 , 60 , 20
union all
select 2, 20 , 20 , 60
```

`0`, `1` and `2` are the Y labels in my test data. In general there are N labels.

For the above data, I should get `180` as output (60+60+60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are bound to your schema/design  - meaning you have columns to represent labels vs array - below should work for you

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SUM(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), 
    CONCAT(r'(?::\d*.*?){', CAST(predictedGroup + 1 AS STRING), r'}:(\d*)')) AS INT64)
  ) AS sum_of_diagonal
FROM `project.dataset.sampleTable` t
```

You can test, play with above with example data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.sampleTable` AS (
  SELECT 0 AS predictedGroup , 60 AS label0 , 20 AS label1, 20 AS label2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 20 , 60 , 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 20 , 20 , 60
)
SELECT SUM(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), 
    CONCAT(r'(?::\d*.*?){', CAST(predictedGroup + 1 AS STRING), r'}:(\d*)')) AS INT64)
  ) AS sum_of_diagonal
FROM `project.dataset.sampleTable` t
```

with result

```
Row sum_of_diagonal  
1   180
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case where you don't want discrete columns for the label values, but instead an array of values since you mention there may be N labels.

If you take that approach for the data representation, it might be something as trivial as this:

```
WITH sampleTable as 
(
select 0 as predictedGroup, [60, 20, 20] as labelVals
union all
select 1, [20 , 60 , 20]
union all
select 2, [20 , 20 , 60]
)

SELECT SUM(labelVals[SAFE_OFFSET(predictedGroup)]) FROM sampleTable
```